# iOS app trouble storing user's documents/photos anywhere other than the phone

Tags: ios, database, storage, kinvey

I'm trying to find a way of letting a user store their photos/documents online for my app. They can upload these to the app after registering an email and they remain on the phone even when the user logs out and then in again. However if the user deletes the app, downloads it again (the developers are using TestFlight at the moment), and logs in, any photo or document that the user saved before deleting has vanished.

I've been told that the data hasn't been stored on the Kinvey SDK service that we have been using as it takes a while to upload the data and then was told the app would be better suited on Kinvey REST API as the SDK version doesn't support background mode which supposedly would help store the data quicker (but this still wouldn't be 100% sure the photos/documents would be stored)

I'm not a developer/coder so I'm afraid I don't know much technically but my app needs to be able to have access across devices for the user's photos and documents, if these are 'lost' it would be catastrophic.

Please could someone help me if there a way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well If you want to save pictures or data that do not get deleted here are few options.

Save them iPhone,iPad gallery if not the use REST API
"Kinvey" can be used for that.

The alternative of "Kinvey", Kindly look into this.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/126098/top-5-parse-alternatives.

and may be you can try this. It provides chat feature too.

http://quickblox.com/